# Angular Lowercase Filter Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

Getting a parse error when attempting the following

```
ui-sref='itemPost({itemID: item.id, itemTitle: item.title | lowercase })'
```

Trying to lowercase the title for the url.

How should I be inserting the filter in this case?

Comment: Is itemPost a function?

Comment: No its the name of the state I am linking to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass filters in function calls like that.

Try this instead:

```
ui-sref='itemPost({itemID: item.id, itemTitle: item.title.toLowerCase() })'
```

Or, make `itemTitle` lowercase in your `itemPost` function.

Comment: Works like a charm! Have to wait a few minutes before accepting!

Comment: Is it possible to then go ui-sref='itemPost({itemID: item.id, itemTitle: item.title.replace(/\s+/g, "-")toLowerCase() })'  ? I seem to be getting a parse error.

Comment: You forgot the `.` before `toLowerCase`. Then again, you may want to do that string manipulation in the function, instead of in the HTML

Comment: I actually have the '.' in there, i think the issue is that the regex is within a quote. I would however it's a link to a state and not a function!

Comment: `itemPost` is a function. Change how _that_ function handles its `itemTitle` parameter.